# How to set profile or config location when running a Spring Boot app from a CRaC checkpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, crac

When running a Spring Boot app using a jar-file, I can specify what profile and configuration file to use as:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=p1 SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:runtime-configuration/application.yaml java -jar app.jar
```

But when running a Spring Boot app from a CRaC checkpoint, these env variables seem to be ignored, like:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=p1 SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:runtime-configuration/application.yaml java -XX:CRaCRestoreFrom=checkpoint
```

The CRaC checkpoint was created with the command:

```
java -Dspring.context.checkpoint=onRefresh -XX:CRaCCheckpointTo=checkpoint -jar app.jar
```

Can I add some custom code in my app to reload the config file and set the active profile when I start the application?